# Difference of assignment when an operation is performed in lists and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I started with Strings & Lists (Basics mostly) and noticed this little thing:

```
String1 = "    Lot of white space  "
String1 = String1.strip()
print(String1)
```

Works like a charm.

When I try the same thing (different operation) on a LIST. Things go south:

```
list1 = [1,5,8,4,2]
list1 = list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

Output - NONE

However:

```
list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

Gives the required output.

**Why is it so?**

Comment: It is convention in Python to have mutating methods `return None` rather than `return self` because it avoids the tendency to chain together a bunch of side-effect inducing code (which can dramatically reduce readability).

Comment: `list.sort()` doesn't return value(actually every function in Python returns a value and if not specified with return - it's `None`), while `str.split()` return new string instance. In Python strings are immutable - i.e. their internal structure can not be changed. List on the other hand are mutable - you can easily change their elements(`a[1] = 1`) without creating new list instances.

Answer (score 1):

From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list.sort#list.sort):

> **sort(*, key=None, reverse=None)** This method **sorts the list in place**,
>   using only < comparisons between items. Exceptions are not suppressed
>   - if any comparison operations fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be left in a partially modified state).
>
> sort() accepts two arguments that can only be passed by keyword
>   (keyword-only arguments):
>   ...
>   **This method modifies the sequence in place** for economy of space when
>   sorting a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side
>   effect, it does not return the sorted sequence (use sorted() to
>   explicitly request a new sorted list instance).

That means, `list1.sort()` will sort the element of `list1` in place without creating any new object or list only returning `None`.

```
>>> list1 = [1,5,8,4,2]
>>> is_None = list1.sort()
>>> is_None is None
True
```

Contrary to `list1.sort()`, [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) (built-in method) instead returns a new sorted list of `list1`:

> `sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])` **Return a new sorted** list from the
>   items in iterable.

```
>>> list_sorted = sorted(list1)
>>> list_sorted
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
>>> type(list_sorted)
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` sorts a list **in place** but returns `None`. The first snippet prints the return value of `sort()`. The second prints the sorted list itself.

Answer (score -1):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) is an in-place method. It *modifies* the list, rather than returning a new list. Its return value is `None`, so `anything = some_list.sort()` sets `anything` to `None`.

From the docs:

> This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when sorting a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side effect, it does not return the sorted sequence (use `sorted()` to explicitly request a new sorted list instance).

If you prefer that syntax (which is perfectly fine), use [`sorted(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) instead of `list.sort`

```
list1 = [1,5,8,4,2]
list1 = sorted(list1)
```